# How to mapping to Entity an ARRAY_AGG columns with LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus

Using the Panache.PanacheEntityBase.find("query") to SELECT data from PostgreSQL.

I do the LEFT JOIN for 2 tables, then use array_agg("text") and alias it to a column.

`SELECT p1_0.unp_status, p1_0.id, array_agg(p2_0.portnumber)`

The native SQL is "OK" but when I convert it to Panache syntax and project it to a class.
I got the error:

> Could not determine appropriate instantiation strategy - no matching
> constructor found and one or more arguments did not define alias for
> bean-injection.

How can I mapping that "array_agg" join column to the Entity or ProjectionClass ?

I try some ways like :

- @Transient
- ProjectionClass {
  private Port port;
  private List portnumber;
  }`

But it still error mapping.

Comment: You can still using native query or register a custom function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76631693/hibernate-6-quarkush2dialect-registerfunction-removed)

Comment: Thanks Luca, 
I think it has the same root cause with the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76094543/hibernate-reactive-dto-projection-issue

Comment: I will try to convert it to STRING_AGG() instead of array_agg. Hope it works!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Quarkus Reactive PgPool instead of the Panache.

- The PgPool support **Row** which helps us to convert to several type of PostgreSQL

> row.getArrayOfStrings('name of the array_agg column')